# How much taping is required to reidentify a wire in a box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cable-management

Quite a number of answers to electrical questions (like this [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/239237/34147)) indicate that a standard /2 cable can be used for a 240V load so long as the white wire is taped (or colored with a marker or paint pen, heat-shrink, etc) to indicate that it is being used as a hot, not a neutral. Other questions, for instance those about wiring 3-way switches, indicate remarking the wires with yellow tape to indicate the travelers.

When remarking a wire to indicate that its use in this instance is *not* as the original insulation color would lead one to believe, is the entire amount of wire visible in the box (at each end) required to be covered, or is it sufficient to make a band by wrapping one or two layers of tape around the wire?

As I see it, the difference would be:

- Completely covered -> a quick glance in the box shows 2 black or a black and a red, therefore it's obviously two hots.
- A band -> a quick glance could show a black and a white leading one to believe there's a hot & neutral. However, a more thorough inspection would show that the white has a band of colored tape, therefore it's two hots.

What is the NEC requirement for thoroughness in remarking a wire to a different color for a different purpose?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'd try to mark the last few inches of the wire, and I've seen some people just wrap one turn of electrical tape and call it good (1/2" or so).  Would be nice to know if it's in the code, or maybe just a standard from trained electricians.

Comment: I am betting for completely covered, just because I usually use a band.

Comment: It seems clear to me that you want to make it clear that you have for example a white conductor marked as yellow.  If you completely cover the conductor, you make that less clear.     Additionally, if I saw a completely wrapped conductor my first assumption would be NOT that it's marked, but that its insulation was damaged.  Looking forward to an answer to the actual question, if code has anything to say on this.

Comment: Interesting thought, @jay613, that one hadn't occurred to me. I'm over here waiting for some sort of code quote as patiently as I can... :) Fortunately, this is a theoretical question ATM, not an urgent need.

Comment: Found this, but it only goes to 2014.  Does not seem to give a good answer to the question.   http://www.ncwhomeinspections.com/Re-Identifying+white+conductors

Comment: AFAIK, but not a code expert so just a comment, the only time the whole wire has to be remarked is from or to green=ground. Actually, I think only one direction is allowed, not sure which one. But the point is that there it is literally "the entire wire", not just "visible in the box". Otherwise, I am pretty sure (but no code citation to prove it) "enough to be clear" and not "all visible in the box".

Comment: I did work on a project once where the exact positioning of labels on wires was precisely documented in the specs.  But it wasn't NEC.  It was the control room of a 1980s nuclear power plant.  I had to use a template to ensure the strip length of each wire was precise to the mm, and the tags were attached the exact distance to the mm away from the end of the insulation, and all oriented correctly.   It's hard to imagine any residential contractor doing anything like that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of the question (mains wiring, greater than 50 volts, etc) NEC stipulates that white-marked conductors be used only as a grounded conductor (ie neutral). Referring to the 2017 edition, the requirement is found in 200.7(A):

> 200.7 Use of Insulation of a White or Gray Color or with Three Continuous White or Gray Stripes.
> (A) General. The following shall be used only for the grounded circuit conductor, unless otherwise permitted in 200.7(B) and (C):
> (1) A conductor with continuous white or gray covering
> (2) A conductor with three continuous white or gray stripes on other than green insulation
> (3) A marking of white or gray color at the termination

Exceptions immediately follow. Paragraph 200.7(C)(1) is applicable to this question:

> (C) Circuits of 50 Volts or More. The use of insulation that is
> white or gray or that has three continuous white or gray stripes
> for other than a grounded conductor for circuits of 50 volts or
> more shall be permitted only as in (1) and (2).
> (1) If part of a cable assembly that has the insulation permanently reidentified to indicate its use as an ungrounded
> conductor by marking tape, painting, or other effective
> means at its termination and at each location where the
> conductor is visible and accessible. Identification shall
> encircle the insulation and shall be a color other than
> white, gray, or green. If used for single-pole, 3-way or
> 4-way switch loops, the reidentified conductor with white
> or gray insulation or three continuous white or gray
> stripes shall be used only for the supply to the switch, but
> not as a return conductor from the switch to the outlet.

These citations do not address the extent to which the mark may or must conceal the original marking of the conductor. It might be useful to survey the code for other instances in which re-marking is addressed to look for a pattern. In 250.119(B)(3), regarding the marking of a conductor in multi-conductor cable for equipment grounding, the code states `Identification shall encircle the conductor.` In section 690.31, regarding wiring methods permitted for PV systems, there is mention of `separate color coding, marking tape, tagging, or other approved means` but again no discussion on the extent of coverage of the original conductor marks. One can understand that tagging would provide a very minimal degree of coverage, however.

Absent specific guidance on the topic, the general requirements of being durable, of good quality, executed in a workman-like manner, etc should be maintained. I see nothing that would lead a person to believe it is necessary to make any effort to conceal the original markings of the conductor.

In my opinion, it would be good practice *not* to fully conceal the original color or markings of the conductor so as to create awareness that the conductor is reidentified. This can serve as warning in case the cable should become exposed in a new place, or in case its marking in another place should become removed.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that a couple of wraps of tape is sufficient. That's handy, as it saves on tape. ;)